# how to play audio object in webOS

Tags: webos, palm-pre

When I press a button I want to play audio object.

Would you be able to give me some advice how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read [the documentation](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1741), or looked at the sample code? What sort of problem are you having?

Comment: i refered documentation and added audio object but it is not working plase send me proper code

Comment: The "documentation" link is broken.

Comment: After a year and a half, I'm not surprised. Apple probably moved it at some point. A search for nssound  would probably turn it up.